# Turn PowerShell Script into Process while Saving Resources

Tags: powershell, automation, process, windows-server

I apologize if this has been answered before, I have not been able to find an adequate answer to my needs here.

I am new to PowerShell. I have picked it up because I have a task I wish to accomplish in Windows Server 2016. I want to trigger a PowerShell script after each security event. It will check the event IDs and if it is the one I am seeking, it will pull certain pieces of data from the event log and add it to a list. I had intended to use Task Scheduler to accomplish this, but I ran into difficulty accounting for multiple events of the same kind happening at the same time. Since I could not easily differentiate between those logs to ensure I captured all of them, I went in a different direction.

```
# event name
$Name = 'Security'

# get an instance
$Log = [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]$Name

# determine what to do when an event occurs
$Action = {
    # get the original event entry that triggered the event
    $Evlog = $event.SourceEventArgs.Entry
    $eventID = $Evlog | Select -ExpandProperty InstanceID

    # do something based on the event
    if ($eventID -eq 4724 -or $eventID -eq 4723)
    {
        $timeWritten = $Evlog | Select -ExpandProperty TimeWritten     
        $targetUserName = $Evlog | Select -ExpandProperty Message
        $subjectUserName = $Evlog | Select -ExpandProperty Message
        $entrytype = $Evlog | Select -ExpandProperty EntryType

        # pulls subject and target username from 4724 logs
        if ($eventID -eq 4724)
        {
            $SubjectUserName1 = (($subjectUserName -split '\r?\n')[$lineNo - 8]).split()[-1]
            $TargetUserName1 = ($targetUserName -split '\r?\n')[$lineNo - 2].split()[-1]
        }
        
        # pulls subject and target username from 4723 logs
        if ($eventID -eq 4723)
        {
            $SubjectUserName1 = (($subjectUserName -split '\r?\n')[$lineNo - 5]).split()[-1]
            $TargetUserName1 = ($targetUserName -split '\r?\n')[$lineNo - 11].split()[-1]
        }

        # searches for email connected to target username
        if ($TargetUserName1 -eq "")
        {
            $TargetEmail1 = "No User Targeted"
        }else {
            try {$TargetEmail1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $TargetUserName1 -Properties * | Select *mail* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "mail"}
            catch{$TargetEmail1 = "User Not Found"}
        }

        # specifying items that are added to list file
        $array = [pscustomobject]@{

        Timewritten = $timeWritten 
        EventID = $eventID
        SubjectUserName = $SubjectUserName1
        TargetUserName = $TargetUserName1
        TargetEmail = $TargetEmail1
        Result = $entrytype -replace ".{5}$"
        }

        # adding to list file
        $array | Export-Csv E:\apps\me\testScript.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
        
        # clear memory
        Get-Event | Remove-Event
        }
    }

# subscribe to its "EntryWritten" event
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $log -EventName EntryWritten -SourceIdentifier 'NewEventHandler' -Action $Action
```

I want to turn the script into a process that is always running, waiting for the events I am looking for and following the rest of the script once one appears. From what I understand, this script can directly pull the event that triggers it, ensuring that each event is accounted for.

When I have the ISE open and run the script, is seems to work as I want it to, but once I close the ISE, the process stops. I want this to be looking for events from startup of the server, and continue indefinitely. In a perfect world, I do not have to download and install a program that helps me do this, but I understand sometimes you simply must. (I have heard of NSSM, is it reliable?) I also want to make sure I do not waste more resources than I must to do this job.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: If you place a `Wait-Event` at the bottom of your script, it will process events indefinitely. You can then use Task Scheduler to launch your script at logon. To get the same effect ad hoc, you can launch the script in a hidden new console window; e.g.: `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden powershell.exe '-File "c:\path\to\your\script.ps1"'`

Comment: To ensure scalability of your script you would have to employ threading so that the watcher launches a new thread that performs the work with pulling the event log entries and updating your list. As you mentioned, there can be complications if the firing event occurs multiple times at the same time.